# Handling clicking event of multiple notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-pendingintent

In my app i have created notification for friends upcoming birthday.if there is more than one friend's birthday it will open multiple notification.
My question:-If i click first notification it has to trigger an Activity.Suppose Activity1
 If i will click another notification it has to trigger another Activity,say Activity2.

Is there any way to do this .please help me.thanks.

```
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Resources res = context.getResources();

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent1 = new Intent(context, FragmentActivity1.class);
        String pass = name;
        resultIntent1.setData(new Uri.Builder().scheme("data")
                .appendQueryParameter("text", "my text").build());
        resultIntent1.putExtra("title", pass);
        resultIntent1.putExtra("uid", i);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder1= TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder1.addParentStack(FragmentActivity1.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder1.addNextIntent(resultIntent1);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent1 = stackBuilder1.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cake)
                .setLargeIcon(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,
                                R.drawable.cake))
                .setTicker("BirthDay " + name)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(name)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent1);

        Notification n = builder.build();
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        nm.notify(i++, n);
```

`

Comment: You should be using only one activity. According to the notification clicked you can populate the activity with content.

Comment: ohk..but always i am getting the same content in the result activity.Suppose i am clicking 1st notification and getting the extra value in result activity.Then if i click 2nd notification also getting the same extra value in the result activity..How i will do it plz help me.

Comment: Use list view for notifications. Register listView.onItemClickListener() so that you can get the position of the item clicked.